# How can I get rid of the static noise in my headphones on the Dell XPS-13 9360?

Tags: dual-boot, audio, dell

The title pretty much says it all. I've tried adjusting the gain with alsamixer to no avail. I am dual-booting alongside Windows 10 if that is relevant.

Comment: I had a similar issue to this on a Dell Precision model. It turned out to be a setting in `tlp` that was powering down the audio card when not actively being used to save power, but it caused significant static when nothing else was playing. Turning that feature of `tlp` off resolved it for me. To clarify: does the static happen all the time, just when playing audio, or just when _not_ playing audio?